# Прогноз временного ряда на будущее

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Друзья, помогите пожалуйста понять как строить прогноз на будущее для временных рядов.
Имеется датасет - продажа прохладительных напитков за период янв2012-дек2018.
Необходимо сделать прогноз продаж "quantity"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я почистил данные, закодировал категориальные переменные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обучил модель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том - как построить прогноз на 2019, 2020 годы..
Я не могу понять как строить прогноз на будущее:

1. без данных по предикторам в будущем, имея только даты;
2. без некоторых предикторов (например без населения городов "pop" и цен "price" ).

Answer (score 3):

А чем вас существующие методы прогнозирования временных рядов не устраивают? Благо даже в сети их выше крыши. Ну вот самый, наверное, популярный:

https://otexts.com/fpp2/data-methods.html

или в кратком изложении:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/multivariate-time-series-guide-forecasting-modeling-python-codes/

Но это не значит, что я рекомендую начинать изучать эту тему с веб-ресурсов. Есть сотни книг по этой теме.
Например:

https://www.wiley.com/en-am/Introduction+to+Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118745113

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401728

[https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Time-Analysis-Prediction-Statistics/dp/1492041653/ref=pd_lpo_1?pd_rd_i=1492041653&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492041653)

[https://www.amazon.com/Deep-Time-Forecasting-Python-Introduction/dp/1540809080](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1540809080)

В том числе и по прогнозированию многомерных временных рядов.

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401728

https://www.wiley.com/en-ru/Multivariate+Time+Series+Analysis+and+Applications-p-9781119502852

А тут многомерный анализ ВР с примерами из финансовой сферы:

https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariate+Time+Series+Analysis%3A+With+R+and+Financial+Applications-p-9781118617908

В том числе и на Python. Например:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

И т.д. Перерасказать это все на форуме -  вряд-ли получиться. Но если в ходе изучения у вас возникнут конкретные вопросы - задавайте. Попробуем помочь.

Теперь по вашим конкретным вопросам.

1. без данных по предикторам в будущем, имея только даты;

Если вы строите многомерную модель -  то никак. Сначала вам надо построить предсказательные модели по каждой из независомой переменных, предсказать их значения в целевом году, а потом используя их строить прогноз вашей основной, зависимой переменной.

2. без некоторых предикторов (например без населения городов "pop" и цен "price" ).

Построив многомерную модель вы вольны из нее исключать те предикторные переменные, которые пожелаете. Понимая, что точность такой модели будет существенно ниже, чем на вашоей "Полной модели". Существует целый раздел теории предсказания многомерных ВР, связанный с отбором значимых для прогноза переменных (feature selection). В приведенных выше источниках все описано максимально детально и подробно.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, я понял по датам правильно и вы прогнозируете продажи за месяц, а не за конкретное число. В самом элементарном варианте вы можете прогнозировать продажи в следующем году по продажам за тот же месяц в предыдущие несколько лет.

Например, учите модель и проверяете:

```
X_train = [продажи_2012,...,продажи_2015]
y_train = [продажи_2016]
X_test = [продажи_2013,...,продажи_2016]
y_test = [продажи_2017]
```

Потом сдвигаете годы и ещё раз проверяете (на той же самой модели!):

```
X_train = [продажи_2013,...,продажи_2016]
y_train = [продажи_2017]
X_test = [продажи_2014,...,продажи_2017]
y_test = [продажи_2018]
```

Если всё проходит хорошо, модель показывает неплохой скор на тесте, можете пытаться предсказывать неизвестные данные:

```
X_train = [продажи_2014,...,продажи_2017]
y_train = [продажи_2018]
X_predict = [продажи_2015,...,продажи_2018]
y_predict = [продажи_2019]

X_train = [продажи_2015,...,продажи_2018]
y_train = [продажи_2019]
X_predict = [продажи_2016,...,продажи_2019]
y_predict = [продажи_2020]
```

Причём, в последнем случае мы опираемся на свои предыдущие прогнозы предыдущего 2019 года, чтобы прогнозировать 2020.

Также можно попробовать предсказывать не продажи, а те данные, которых у вас не хватает: `pop`, `price`, и потом пользоваться этими предсказаниями в той модели, которой вы ранее пользовались.

В общем, варианты тут есть, но нужно понимать - никогда нельзя "забегать вперёд", когда вы строите модели. Модель всегда должна предсказывать по прошлым годам последующие и никак по-другому.